# Help regarding java swing/GridBagLaytout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm currently trying to implement a Swing/GUI that could be regarded as a **RDF** editor.

For each property , I can add/remove one ore more widgets storing the values (JTextField, JScrollPane+JTextArea, JCombo, etc.... ).

[image: balsamiq]

I've been trying to use the **GridBagLayout** to put the Components in place but I can get any good result. Any suggestion about how I should use the GridBagLayout for this design ? Or should I use another LayoutManager ?

Thanks,

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using [Mig Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/); it's a grid-based layout manager.